# Application insights group with regex

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have the following problem, we have some .net Web API's which i want to monitor.
So lets say i have one basic API which has one Method with the following options:

```
/api/appliances/list
/api/appliances/list/userid
/api/appliances/list/userid/appliancecategory
```

In fact i have some more operations, but this is not really important,

So i want a query which gets the average response type per operation
I am able to select it with a regex like this:

```
requests
| where  name matches regex "^GET \\/api\\/appliances\\/categories\\/[\\w]+$"
```

Does someone have an idea how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `| project name, xxx` to end of the query.

A similar issue can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92394128-c5ca-48b9-9d19-61598ec27484/application-insights-analytics-query-fails-to-parse-regex-for-amp39match-regexamp39-operator?forum=ApplicationInsights).